# AI for deciding how many machine I need to save cloud costs

Tags: automation, cloud, artificial-intelligence, scale

### Background

I running a Kubernetes cluster based on Micro-services architecture. My traffic is depends on many factors. The most important for them is - The day of the week and the time.

In order to save costs, I made a rule to scale down the machine in specific time of week.

For example, on weekend - I'm running less machine then in the middle of the week.

### The problem

"Weekend" is good point to be based on, but it's not enough. Why? Because there are few more factory - like:

- holidays (uhm.. Christmas) that the traffic in supper slow.
- Previous Usage history. Let's say that my specific clients are never working on January. So, the traffic will go down.

So, in order to create a smart scaling metric, I need to know:

- Dates - day of week, holidays, ...
- Usage history - how many traffic was on same day, previous year\month\week.

Assuming I have those two metrics (mentioned above).

**Sound to me like a great problem to be solved with AI.** Also, sound like a product that can be public, not something that everyone needs to develop it self. It's general problem for anyone who running on cloud.

### The question

1. Did you hear about something like this?
2. Any other strategy to solve the problem will be great!

Comment: I think this problem is better solved by creating a usage estimator, but what work have you already done? The first steps would be to set up the cost function for (users/services/machines) and their dependencies. Then you also need to tell us how far into the future the estimator needs to look. If you can scale up/down within an hour, you don't really need an estimator and can just react from your program.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.